# How do I add a custom font from online to a TextView in an app, but using XML?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I want to add a custom Samsung font called SamsungOne to an Android app, I know you can link a font from online to put on a website, but how do you do this for an app, but using XML? Java is fine, but XML would be better. Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't want to use typeface?

Answer (score 1):

Add your `.ttf` downloaded from internet in `app  ⟶ src  ⟶ main  ⟶ assets`. 
Then you can use this code snippet to apply it to your textviews, edit texts etc.

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "century_gothic.ttf"); 
                   // century_gothic.ttf is the name of your .ttf file stored in assets.
t.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy that font in asset folder and use it . With java :

```
typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                        typefaceName);
```

To use it from xml you need to create a custom View(TextView or Edittext whatever you want).In attrs.xml you can define all types of type face and use the attribute to set Typeface. See the custom implementation of Edit text below:-

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    handleStyleable(context, attrs);
}
public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    handleStyleable(context, attrs);
}

private void handleStyleable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFont);
    FONT_VAL font_val= FONT_VAL.NONE;
    try {
        for (FONT_VAL mode : FONT_VAL.values()) {
            if (ta.getInt(R.styleable.CustomFont_typeface, 3) == mode.getId()) {
                font_val = mode;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (font_val == FONT_VAL.MEDIUM_FONT) {
            setTypeface(AppUtil.getTypeface(context, Constants.FontName.MEDIUM));
        }else if(font_val== FONT_VAL.REGULAR_FONT){
            setTypeface(AppUtil.getTypeface(context, Constants.FontName.REGULAR));
        }else if(font_val== FONT_VAL.LIGHT_FONT){
            setTypeface(AppUtil.getTypeface(context, Constants.FontName.LIGHT));
        }else if(font_val== FONT_VAL.ITALIC){
            setTypeface(AppUtil.getTypeface(context, Constants.FontName.ITALIC));
        }else if(font_val== FONT_VAL.BOLD){
            setTypeface(AppUtil.getTypeface(context, Constants.FontName.BOLD));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public enum FONT_VAL {
NONE(0),MEDIUM_FONT(1), REGULAR_FONT(2),LIGHT_FONT(3), ITALIC(4),BOLD(5);
private final int ID;
FONT_VAL(final int id) {
    this.ID = id;
}
public int getId() {
    return ID;
}
```

Define the custom attribute for each font in attrs.xml:-

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
    <attr name="typeface" format="enum">
        <enum name="medium_font" value="1" />
        <enum name="regular_font" value="2" />
        <enum name="light_font" value="3" />
        <enum name="italic" value="4" />
        <enum name="bold" value="5" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Then you can directly use it in XMl :

```
    <com.views.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:typeface="bold" />
```

To set the font from external storage you need to do it at runtime only :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "font.ttf"));
```